# Could not find method AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-services

When trying to run Android project on my Meizu MX3, I get the problem mentioned in topic.

My logcat out is:

> 04-23 01:05:01.855: I/dalvikvm(18549): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo, referenced from method com.myapp.deviceinfo.AndroidDeviceInfo$1.run
>   04-23 01:05:01.855: W/dalvikvm(18549): VFY: unable to resolve static method 14581: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient;.getAdvertisingIdInfo (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
>   04-23 01:05:01.855: D/dalvikvm(18549): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0005
>   04-23 01:05:01.885: W/dalvikvm(18549): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 2144 (Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;)
>   04-23 01:05:01.885: W/dalvikvm(18549): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0xa4
>   04-23 01:05:01.885: W/dalvikvm(18549): VFY:  rejected Lcom/myapp/deviceinfo/AndroidDeviceInfo$1;.run ()V
>   04-23 01:05:01.885: W/dalvikvm(18549): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x00a4
>   04-23 01:05:01.885: W/dalvikvm(18549): VFY:  rejected Lcom/myapp/deviceinfo/AndroidDeviceInfo$1;.run ()V
>   04-23 01:05:01.885: W/dalvikvm(18549): Verifier rejected class Lcom/myapp/deviceinfo/AndroidDeviceInfo$1;

Any help is going to be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a big problem that made me stunned for a days.

I had tried all methods, like Proguard editing, changing libraries, context changing, but this solved the problem: simple update to new SDK build version 22.0.1; this fixed the issue.